# How to add user images on markers in google maps?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I'm building an angular app in which I require user profile images to be shown on google map as markers.

The location comes from an API as JSON with Lat, long and images of user.
Plus, I'm using clustering in maps. Whenever I click the cluster, the markers with images should appear.

I'm trying it both AGM maps library as well as Google Maps Javascript API
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  StackOverflow is a place where you can come for help with your code, but we can't write code from scratch for you.

Comment: @Graham I tried using custom overlays, but the image in overlay doesn't scale when zoom in and out.

Comment: Please go to the help section here and read about what makes a good question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

To use custom markers and use your own images. You simply have to pass the url of your image to the an `icon` property of the `Marker` object as below...

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        icon: 'http://contoso.com/image.png',
        map: map
      });
```

if you need more control over that image and how it is rendered. Google Maps API provides and [`icon` object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon) you can use

```
var icon = {
    url: 'http:contoso.com/image.png',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
}
```

There are a lot of documentation and examples in [Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/) website

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use google maps default marker and want to add custom HTML to markers, 
Check this plugin out - https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker 
Really easy plugin to use HTML as google maps markers.

Note - Basically this plugin uses custom overlay as markers. So, compared with default google maps markers, I think using this makes the map becomes a bit heavy to pan around when there are many markers (especially on smartphone)